# About Match Objects in python

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and am trying to run the below code:

```
import re

start([default])

email = 'akshay.bung17@gmail.com'

m = re.search('kit',email)

print m.group()
```

But i keep getting the following error:

```
start([default])
```

> NameError: name 'start' is not defined

Can anyone please let me know what exactly is happening over here?

Comment: Yeah, the error message is quite clear: you are using a variable, `start` that you haven't defined yet. For that matter, `default` hasn't been defined either. Only you can say what you are trying to do there, though...

Comment: What the heck did you expect `start([default])` to do?

Answer (score 1):

As people have said in the comments, this error message means exactly what it says - you never defined `start`.

I'd strongly suggest reading [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) on how to debug small programs.

Comment: Sure Thank You for the responses! I will look into the article.